# The use of since and for

Tags: grammaticality

When we use since and for in the present perfect and in the past simple
e.g. He lived here next door to me for three years.

why didn't we use has lived or has been living?

Answer (score 2):

The tense names are helpful in answering this question. The *past tense* in:

> He lived here next door to me for three years.

indicates that he no longer lives here.

The *present tense* (perfect simple / perfect continuous) in the other two sentences:

> He has lived here next door to me for three years.
>
> He has been living here next door to me for three years.

indicates that he is still living here.

Note: it is just possible to imagine a context where *He has lived here next door to me for three years* (present perfect simple) does not mean that he is still living next door. For example, you could be listing all the places he has lived in his life:

> He's lived for two years in New York; he's lived in an apartment in
>   Paris for 6 months; he's lived here next door to me for three years;
>   and now he's living in the Australian outback.

Comment: In the exam paper what can I answer? . He ....(visit).......the village for two years.

Comment: It depends what is being tested. Out of context each of the three forms is grammatical, albeit with different meanings: _visited, has visited, has been visiting_.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I know well the difference between the present perfect simple and the present perfect continuous.I understood that the difference between the present perfect simple and the past simple that the present perfect simple indicates a speech about experience but the past simple is about completed actions. Am I right?

Comment: @Muhammad. I'm afraid that the grammar of the present perfect and past simple is far too complex to reduce to a simple statement such as the one you make above. I recommend getting a reputable grammar book such as _Swan's Practical English Usage_ so that you can pursue this question in depth. But, yes, the most common use of the past simple is for completed actions or states,